# jQuery if click contained clicked class

Tags: jquery

If I have a listener for the *clicked* class and another one for *click-option-1*, *click-option-2*, and *click-option-3*, how can I tell within my *clicked* event listener if *click-option-3* was clicked?

```
<div class="clicked">
   <div class="click-option-1">1</div>
   <div class="click-option-2">2</div>
   <div class="click-option-3">3</div>
</div>

$( '.clicked' ).on( "touchstart mousedown", function(event) {

if .click-option-3 was not clicked do something.

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.clicked').on('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('click-option-3')){
        //Do This.
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how you would do the same thing only with an id?

Comment: with an `id`... instead of `.hasClass('className')`, try `.is('#id')`